# How to encrypt files in iPhone (PDF files)

Tags: iphone, ipad, encryption

i am developing a ebook reader and sending the ipa files to various people. The ipa files contains some PDF books. Is there any way in which i can encrypt the PDf files so that the user can see them only on device and not on PC... thanku

Answer (score 1):

That's a general security question and the answer is: No. If one device (the iPhone) can decrypt the files without further data like a password or secret device key, another device (a desktop computer) can do this as well.

All you can do is obfuscate the files. That would keep people from simply unzipping the ipa and opening the PDFs. But any measure you take makes it only a little more difficult to access the files. There's no way to make it *impossible* for a skilled person to get at the data.

Comment: hi nikolai, thanku for the answer.... But the end users are not really skilled.. they are 10th grade kids.. Atleast we should be able to secure the content from them... Is there anyway i can do it?? can u please tell me a bit more on obfuscation...

Comment: Infact you got exactly what i want... I want the user to not to unzip the ipa file. thats our main requirement.... it would be really nice if you can provide me with some more inputs regarding the obfuscation...  Some sample code would be really helpful as i am very new to iOS development.....

Comment: @A There are lots of ways to obfuscate files. The most basic way would be to just obfuscate file names, like `foo.dat`. If the extension isn't PDF, that's enough for most people to keep them from opening the files directly. You can also obfuscate the data, like XORing the first couple of KBytes with a constant value.

Comment: @ Nikolai Ruhe hey bro i also want to change the extension of pdf like u suggested but wht is the procedure for tht? if i m doing apple.xyz then user cnt open tht pdf on other device but how can i do again apple.pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

You could re-save the bundle pdf's using data protection, its not bulletproof but it makes is difficult to read the data (especially if the passcode is unknown), however it only works if the devices are pass-coded.

```
//There is probobly a quicker way to do this..ie..iterating the bundle programatically for pdf's
NSMutableArray * a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     
    [a addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pdf1.pdf"]];
    [a addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pdf2.pdf"]];
    [a addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pdf3.pdf"]];
    [self resaveFilesWithProtection:a]; 
    [a release];



    -(void)resaveFilesWithProtection:(NSArray*)fileNameArray
    {

        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString * DocPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];       
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];                        

        for (NSString* s in fileNameArray) {        

        NSString * fullFilepath = [DocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:s];//getting path to file 
            NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];//getting data out of old file    
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fullFilepath error:NULL];//deleting old file

        NSError*er=nil;     
        [myData writeToFile:fullFilepath options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete error:&er];    //saving back to disk with protection       
        }   



  NSLog(@"DONE");
}
```

You could also store the NSData in an SQLite database, or obscure the file extensions by re-saving them as .anything.

Edit:

If you don't want the user to be able to unzip the ipa and you think that extension obscuring isn't enough then your going to have to not put the pdf's in the bundle and pull them down from the network.

Comment: You cannot remove the files from the app bundle.

Comment: Hi luke.. thanks for the detailed reply... Can i know what is meant by "device pass coding" and how to do it???

Comment: @alpha this just means setting a password for the device. (Settings>general>Passcode Lock>Turn Passcode On)

Comment: @Nikolai just tried this and it *did* remove the data, however obviously if the ipa is attacked rather than the bundle in the application sandbox your statement still stands.